# How to choose random image from image set in javascript

Tags: javascript, random, image

I have been using the following code to generate random images, but none of the pictures are showing up.

```
<html>

<head>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

var theImages = new Array() 

theImages[0] = '<img class="atvi-image-image" alt=""src="/content/dam/atvi/callofduty/blackops2/cod-bo2/dlc/mdlc-calling-card-flags.png" title="" height="467" width="675">'
theImages[1] = '<img class="atvi-image-image" alt="" src="/content/dam/atvi/callofduty/blackops2/cod-bo2/dlc/mdlc-nuketown-zombies.png" title="" height="732" width="1084">'
theImages[2] = '<img class="atvi-image-image" alt="" src="/content/dam/atvi/callofduty/blackops2/cod-bo2/dlc/mdlc-extra-slots.png" title="" height="480" width="752">'
theImages[3] = '<img class="atvi-image-image" alt="" src="/content/dam/atvi/callofduty/blackops2/cod-bo2/dlc/mdlc-nuketown-2025.png" title="" height="412" width="683">'



var j = 0
var p = theImages.length;
var preBuffer = new Array()
for (i = 0; i < p; i++){
preBuffer[i] = new Image()
preBuffer[i].src = theImages[i]
}
var whichImage = Math.round(Math.random()*(p-1));
function showImage(){
document.write(theImages[whichImage]);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
showImage();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You're missing a closing quote for src="" and the end of the img tag ( '/>') in your 'document.write' call

Comment: Do people not bother ending lines these days?`;`

Comment: @Wezly Why should they?

Comment: @Wezly, which line are you refering to?

Comment: Many lines of your javascript Chuck. @Ian I don't know, kinda why I asked - I still do out of good practice, other languages I write are more fussy and require them. Just a good habit i suppose..

Comment: lines should always be closed.

the semicolon insertion should be counted as part of the debugger, not part of the compiler!

the main reason to close your lines are documented well on other places, i will just mention here that they dont do what you think in too many edge cases to use the semicolon insertion reliably.

if you are a js pro and you understand the rules of insertion you may not insert them, but then a noob will see your script, use it, adapt it, move the true of a return true to the next line and break everything.

Comment: @Wezly verbose languages like Java and C.* require semicolons and ignore whitespace. Awesome languages like ruby and javascript treat as statement separators, but let you use semicolons too/instead. Javascript does that by inserting semicolons around until it makes sense, as long as there's a newline or a right curly. In ruby, it's bad practice to use a semicolon (or `then`) _and_ a newline. In Javascript, no-one really cares (except you cannot linebreak right after `return` (or a labeled break) without getting an extra semicolon inserted there). I do like semicolons in procedural code, though

Comment: @jascha when they split `return true` to multiple lines, thing break, semicolons or not. I don't think semicolons will motivate said noobs to not split returs either.

Comment: @Wezly Okay, I just wanted to make sure you didn't think they were required. I like to always include them, but it's not necessary. It is in some situations, but if you structure your code properly, it shouldn't be a problem to not use them

Comment: @jascha There aren't "many edge cases". There's a few. If you know the language and write/structure your code properly, you shouldn't have a problem not using semicolons. I always use them, but it's far from required/suggested/needed. If noobs split up a `return` statement, then they get an exception, and they either research it on the Internet or come to StackOverflow to find out why. There's no problem with that

Comment: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3057#issuecomment-5135512

Comment: i dont want to get into this discussion here too,
but the first three posts sum the problem up pretty well.
semicolon insertion is confusing for newbies and pros alike.
and, even if the compiler can insert them it doesnt mean that its right to make it do it.

Answer (score 3):

You already have the **full** `<img>` tag in the array. So just use:

```
document.write(theImages[whichImage]);
```

Although I would advise against using `document.write`. Of course, in your situation, where it's being executed in the middle of HTML, I don't see much of a problem. It would be bad if `document.write` were executed after the page was rendered. Normally, the preferred method is something like the `appendChild` method or even setting `innerHTML`, although it would take some refactoring to get your code to use them.

Here's an example of how I'd set it up:

```
(function () {
    var theImages = [{
        src: "http://www.techinasia.com/techinasia/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/smile.png",
        width: "675",
        height: "467"
    }, {
        src: "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQdcHlJqgIKNOS0DaEjO31xK1zYtmJlza8z70ljiKFbo2ZgLdh9eA",
        width: "1084",
        height: "732"
    }, {
        src: "http://cdn2-b.examiner.com/sites/default/files/styles/large_lightbox/hash/68/d1/68d11ab242d40c8d5abbe8edb58fd4ed_0.jpg?itok=M3qtK47_",
        width: "200",
        height: "200"
    }];

    var preBuffer = [];
    for (var i = 0, j = theImages.length; i < j; i++) {
        preBuffer[i] = new Image();
        preBuffer[i].src = theImages[i].src;
        preBuffer[i].width = theImages[i].width;
        preBuffer[i].height = theImages[i].height;
    }

    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

    window.getRandomImage = function () {
        var whichImage = getRandomInt(0, preBuffer.length - 1);
        return preBuffer[whichImage];
    }
})();

window.onload = function () {
    var newImage = getRandomImage();
    console.log(newImage);
    document.body.appendChild(newImage);
};
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/wFjGv/

This code uses a new object to hold the details for each image. That way, you can easily set and get each image's properties that you need without hardcoding HTML.

It preloads the images in the `preBuffer` array, and when needed, an image is retrieved from the array, and put into the `<body>`. You can change its target in the `onload` event. The `getRandomImage` function returns a random image from that array. I updated the method of getting a random integer as well.

Comment: I changed it to document.write(theImages[whichImage]); but it is still not working, thank you for your help though.

Comment: @ChuckNorris It should work fine. Anyways, I added code to my answer of how I would handle it, and it seems to be more organized and works as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting an `<img src=` something that is not what you want.  Your array (`theImages`) is storing full `<img>` tags, not just the link to that image.

Either change you `theImages` array to store values like so:

```
theImages[0] = "/content/dam/atvi/callofduty/blackops2/cod-bo2/dlc/mdlc-calling-card-flags.png"
```

OR use the current setup as the image tag.

```
document.write(theImages[whichImage]);
```

Also:

- With random numbers, you should probably stick to `Math.floor()` lest
  you round over your max length.
- `var j = 0` is missing a `;`
- `theImages` img tags are not closed (`<img ... />`

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
var srcs = [
    "/content/dam/atvi/callofduty/blackops2/cod-bo2/dlc/mdlc-calling-card-flags.png",
    "/content/dam/atvi/callofduty/blackops2/cod-bo2/dlc/mdlc-nuketown-zombies.png",
    "foo/bar.jpg"
    ], imgs = [];
function init() {
    "use strict";
    var i, x, div;
    div = document.createElement('div');
    div.id = 'imageContainer';
    document.querySelector('body').appendChild(div);
    for (i = 0; i < srcs.length; i += 1) {
        x = new Image();
        x.src = srcs[i];
        imgs.push(x);
    }
}
function showRandom() {
    "use strict";
    document.querySelector('#imageContainer').innerHTML = imgs[Math.random * imgs.length];
}
init();
```

To add a random image-

```
showRandom();
```

---

**PS** - You shouldn't use `document.write`, but if you do, you should close the stream by `document.close`, to tell the browser to finish loading the page. [Read more - MDN JS Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.write)